# How can I select this ID?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();        

public class Doc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Doc> Docs{ get; set; }
```

How can I select Doc Id so I can set this to 0:

```
db.DocId = 0;
```

The above did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Do you want to update the value for every single `Doc` ? Or just one ?

Comment: Just one, the one I selected, Im following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hg3H_pAzoPI @ 13:05

Comment: You haven't selected anything the example. How do you select it ? Based on which criteria ?

Comment: Also, can you add a bit of context as to why you're setting the `Doc`'s id to `0` ?

Comment: Why does the person in the video set the ID to 0?

Comment: When in the video does this happen ? I don't want to watch 30 minutes of video ... Plus, if you do not understand why you're doing this you should probably either use an other tutorial or re-watch this one while paying more attention. You should understand why you're setting the ID to 0. (I personally have no clue at this moment, it's your code :-) )

Comment: It happens at 13:05, I think its to select none

Comment: As I understand it, it has nothing to do with Entity Framework. In the video he sets the model's id to 0 to reinitialize the "current user". I think you might need to re-think what you're trying to achieve with this code and to give us a wide picture of your code because for now i can't really make sense of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes how do I do that with the code first approach Im using?